# Connect two strokes perfectly in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

I have these two separate strokes - how would I go about connecting them perfectly, so there is no bend[image] where they meet?

Answer (score 2):

You can select both endpoints with the direct select tool (A) and then do Command (or Control)-Option-J to Average the points (the default selection of Both usually works for me). Then Command (or Control)-J to Join the points.

Answer (score 0):

If the anchor points are from different paths you can do this:

1) Select the 2 end-points with the direct select tool (A).

2) At the top bar under the anchor section, select `Connect Selected End Points`.

[image: anchor point selection]

You can then delete one of the anchor points and adjust the curve.